# Increase 'Follow' limit from 500 in MS Dynamics CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

Our users have reached their follow limit adn we want to look at increasing it. We are on Rollup 11 (I know that Rollup 12 automatically increases this from 500 to 1000).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I won't state that it is impossible, there may be some unknown registry value to change it, but nobody around seems to know it

There's someone who says it, though(quote "Limit of 500 follows, not configurable"): http://julieyack.blogs.com/my_weblog/2012/04/the-net-difference-in-crm-2011-rtm-and-crm-2011-now.html